# How to call java method from Postgres trigger

Tags: java, postgresql

In my requirement need to Invoke java method or webservice while a record is insert or update in to a Table.

I am using Postgres (9.5) Database , How can I invoke the java method?

Comment: what is inserting a record into the DB?

Comment: I'm not sure "invoke the Java method" even makes sense, because Postgres does not run on a JVM.  Postgres may have some extensions which can make an API call, but even then you'd be calling some Java webservice, and not Java directly.

Comment: So where is that "Java method"  located? Is that exposed as a web service in an application server? Do you only have a JAR file?

Comment: Possible, but involves plenty of trickery: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21632243/how-do-i-get-asynchronous-event-driven-listen-notify-support-in-java-using-a-p

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: well there is, PL/Java but that is not a road I would like to take. For one it's not actively maintained but more importantly it starts one JVM for **every** connection which is a huge overhead.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sounds like it.  But read the very first comment, I'll bet there is a workaround here which doesn't require calling Java from Postgres.

Comment: Use AOP to call another method inside your java program whenever the method call to persist data happens.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , web service is in application server

Comment: This is a seriously bad idea. It will slow down your transactions unpredictably. Use some queuing or messaging technique and an asynchronous worker process.

Comment: So you need to make a HTTP call to an application server, not "call a java method"

Comment: yes, I need to invoke the service. How can I achieve this one.

Comment: I seriously recommend looking at the link I gave in my comment. For the sheer interest value, not really as a solution for this question.

Comment: yes @Kayaman, I'll refer this link.

Comment: I was actually suggesting that to the other commenters. It is quite interesting what you can do with Postgres when you switch to a different driver.