# How to listen for database changes triggered by a 3rd party application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I need to integrate a Ruby on Rails application with a 3rd-party application, which will share a common PostgreSQL database. That is, both the Rails app and the 3rd-party app will be using the same PG database.

Is it possible to set a listener within the Rails app, such that an event is fired when the 3rd-party app adds, edits or deletes a database record?

For example, say I have a `Book` model defined in Rails, and the 3rd-party app adds a new row in the database's Book table (not via the `BooksController`).

Can the Rails application detect that a new record has been added, or that an existing record has been edited/deleted?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not used to Ruby nor PostgreSQL, but the arquitechture is much te same for this case.

I think you should use a trigger to listen the bbdd for changes:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html

Then you can call a webservice from that PostgreSQL script to tell Rails app it has been an update:

[Postgresql - detect changes and call webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505286/postgresql-detect-changes-and-call-webservice)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I finally did: Use [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever), because it integrates nicely with Capistrano and showed me how to run Rails code from within cron. My missing peace was basically

script/runner -e production 'ChangeObserver.recentchanges'
which is now run every 5 minutes. The recentchanges reads the last looked-at ID from a tmp-file, pulls all new Change records which have a higher ID than that and runs the normal observer code for each record (and saves the highest looked-at ID to the tmp-file, of course).